Electron Share Audio & Desktop screen
I created a sharing screen and audio app, and everything is working fine but for many users, there is always missing sound either desktop sound or microphone while no errors
I tried to get the specific audio device for the microphone as the exact ID but it's still the same, with the exact-ID I have to listen for audio source changes, and when changes occur and successfully changes the sender audio the audio is gone
const createStream = async () => {
    try {
      const stream = await (navigator.mediaDevices as any).getUserMedia({
        audio: {
          // echoCancellation: true,
          // noiseSuppression: true,
          // sampleRate: 44100,
          autoGainControl: false,
          echoCancellation: false,
          googAutoGainControl: false,
          noiseSuppression: false,
          volume: 1,
          // channelCount: 2,
          // deviceId: { exact: id },
        },
        video: false,
      });
      const stream1 = await (navigator.mediaDevices as any).getUserMedia({
        audio: {
          mandatory: {
            chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
          },
        },

        video: {
          mandatory: {
            chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
          },
        },
      });

      const combineStreams = new MediaStream([
        ...stream.getTracks(),
        ...stream1.getTracks(),
      ]);

      return combineStreams;
    } catch (e: any) {
      // handle errors
    }
  };


  const handelPeer = async (peerId: string, user_type: string) => {
   // ... create peer connection
   peer.on('open', () => {
      connection.on('open', async () => { 
           dataSream.current = await createStream();
        callRef.current = peer.call(peerId, dataSream.current);
       }
    });
  }

